# LibreOffice takes long time to open

Tags: arch-linux, libreoffice

I'm running Arch Linux with KDE Plasma desktop environment.

When I open any LibreOffice program lately, it takes several minutes to open. It hangs for some time on the "LibreOffice Community" loading prompt.

How do I figure out what is causing this delay?

UPDATE: Running `libreoffice --calc` shows no output.

UPDATE 2: Runnning `strace` as described by @terdon in the comments gets me this output:

```
read(4, "20%\n", 255)                   = 4
futex(0x558a4eecc7a8, FUTEX_WAIT_BITSET_PRIVATE|FUTEX_CLOCK_REALTIME, 0, {tv_sec=1691506856, tv_nsec=487567000}, FUTEX_BITSET_MATCH_ANY) = -1 ETIMEDOUT (Connection timed out)
futex(0x558a4eecc7b0, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 1) = 0
poll([{fd=3, events=POLLIN|POLLOUT}], 1, -1) = 1 ([{fd=3, revents=POLLOUT}])
writev(3, [{iov_base="8\2\4\0\2\0`\4\4\0\0\0fff\0C\0\5\0\1\0`\4\2\0`\4\36\0\221\0"..., iov_len=72}, {iov_base=NULL, iov_len=0}, {iov_base="", iov_len=0}], 3) = 72
recvmsg(3, {msg_namelen=0}, 0)          = -1 EAGAIN (Resource temporarily unavailable)
recvmsg(3, {msg_namelen=0}, 0)          = -1 EAGAIN (Resource temporarily unavailable)
recvmsg(3, {msg_namelen=0}, 0)          = -1 EAGAIN (Resource temporarily unavailable)
recvmsg(3, {msg_namelen=0}, 0)          = -1 EAGAIN (Resource temporarily unavailable)
read(4,
```

Comment: Which package are you using: `libreoffice-fresh` or `libreoffice-still`? I'm running the exact same environment and have not experienced this.

Comment: @ajgringo619 libreoffice-fresh

Comment: Try running it from the terminal and post the results here; add to your question, please: `libreoffice`

Comment: @ajgringo619 done

Comment: Maybe try `strace libreoffice 2>aaa &` and then do `tail -f aaa` to see what it's doing when it gets stuck?

Comment: @terdon Updated

Comment: Huh. I've been using LibreOffice on my Arch for several years now and had never seen the issue. Just now, when I did `strace libreoffice 2>aaa` to compare to what you show, I got _exactly_ the same behavior: it was stuck on `read(4,` for several seconds but eventually opened. I did run a `pacman -Suy` yesterday, so I'm guessing it has something to do with a newer version. Have you been seeing this behavior for a long time? The fact that I only get it today suggests it's an upstream bug that, I hope, will be fixed soon.

Comment: What version of libreoffice are you on? I'm now on 
`Version: 7.5.5.2 (X86_64) / LibreOffice Community
Build ID: 50(Build:2)
CPU threads: 8; OS: Linux 6.4; UI render: default; VCL: gtk3
Locale: en-US (en_US.UTF-8); UI: en-US
7.5.5-1
Calc: threaded`

Comment: @terdon Version: `7.5.4.2 (X86_64) / LibreOffice Community
Build ID: 50(Build:2)
CPU threads: 12; OS: Linux 6.4; UI render: default; VCL: kf5 (cairo+xcb)
Locale: en-US (en_US.UTF-8); UI: en-US
7.5.4-3
Calc: threaded`